# Can we use unique key as primary key?

Tags: sql

(interview question)
if i have a table without primary key can i use unique key as a primary key or not ?

Comment: Yes, You can but Unique key will allow 1 null value as 1 null value would be unique to the column.

Answer (score 2):

A primary key has three properties:

- The key values uniquely define each row.
- None of the key values are `NULL`.
- There is only one per table.

A unique key satisfies the first of these conditions.  If it satisfies the second, then it is a *candidate primary key*.  And, if so, it could be chosen as the primary key if no other primary key is already defined.  However, unique constraints allow `NULL` values, so this is not always true.